# My UITextView makes my App crash when back button is pressed to get back to the menu in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview

This is the code I have in my .h

```
@interface Notebook : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UITextView *textView;

//loads "Data Saved" message after save button hit
IBOutlet UILabel *loaded;
}

//Database Actions

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender;


@end
```

And here is my code in the .m

```
@implementation Notebook {

}

//Saves loaded Data

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

//First Save String
NSString *saveString = textView.text;
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:saveString forKey:@"saveString"];
[defaults synchronize];

//Shows saved data message
loaded.text = @"Data Saved";

}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Automatically loads Data on re-enter of screen
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadString = [defaults objectForKey:@"saveString"];
    [textView setText:loadString];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
if ([textView isFirstResponder] && [touch view] != textView) {
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Any crash logs? Also try to set the exception breakpoint to be thrown on all exception to see on which line the app crashes.

Comment: No Crash Logs, the only thing that happens is it goes to "Thread 1" and it says [Notebook .cxx_destruct] and I'm getting a green line across that says breakpoint, the code in there is "0x10ce4e8:  movl   %edi, (%esp)
"

Comment: What is the exception breakpoint? I'm fairly new to Xcode.  Thanks @verbumdei

Comment: Try this :) http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions

Comment: @verbumdei ... that blog is exactly what happened to me.  I followed what he did, but the result still made it crash. I ended up deleting the break point for the line that it was showing after it crashed, and it seemed to fix the problem... will that come back to haunt me? Thanks in advance for such quick responses!

Comment: On which line the app crashed? The removal of breakpoint will not solve your back button issue.

Comment: what about your back button action???

Comment: @verbumdei, I haven't had an issue using the back button in my app after I removed that breakpoint... I haven't detected a crash since I did remove that breakpoint at all!